# Replacing one JTextArea with another

Tags: java, user-interface, jtextarea

In my GUI a have a JTextArea within a JScrollPane that is attached to a container.

```
        ta = new JTextArea();
        jsp = new JScrollPane(ta);

        container.add(jsp);
```

I want to be able to replace this JTextArea with another JTextArea, for example

```
JTextArea ta1 = new JTextArea("New text area");
ta = ta1;
ta.repaint();
```

However, when I reassign this JTextArea nothing in the GUI changes. Is there a better/correct way for doing this?

Comment: What should happen before the JTextArea is replaced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just replace text of textarea with new one.

```
newTextArea.setText(oldTextArea.getText())
```

or simply put new text by

```
newTextArea.setText("new text")
```

Comment: Yes, I'd actually just worked this out myself. Thanks! Just out of interest, do you know of a way to replace a JTextArea (i.e. how I was originally trying to do it)?

Comment: I dont understand the need of creating new JTextArea. If it is already created and its in GUI then just replace text and remove it from GUI. If it is not created then just replace text no need of creating new one.

Answer (score 1):

```
ta = ta1;
```

If you want a component to be shown in a GUI then you need to add(...) the component to the GUI.

```
panel.add(ta1);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

Changing the reference does not add a component to the GUI.

This is your second question that attempts to play with the reference of a variable in order to access a GUI component. Again I ask the question why are you doing this. It wasn't required in your last question and I doubt it is required in this question. You have some kind of design problem.

Comment: @Matt, you still are not addressing your main issue because you haven't stated what your requirement is, therefore we can't suggest possible better approaches. All you have stated is how you are attempting to solve the problem which is not a requirement.